# Serialize and Deserialize TimeSpan between Json.Net and System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a asp.net core web api that uses System.Text.Json for serializing to JSON. On my Blazor wasm client I use json.net, since NSwag generates the client with that. Now I have an issue during deserialization of TimeSpans. I Already have added a custom converter:

```
    public override TimeSpan Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => TimeSpan.Parse(reader.GetString() ?? string.Empty);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TimeSpan value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
```

For a `TimeSpan.FromHours(3.5)` this returns this json value `03:30:00` which looks fine for me. But when I try to parse that in json.net I get the following exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type 'System.TimeSpan' because the type requires a JSON primitive
> value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.

So I checked what json.net itself produces here and this value came out: `\"02:30:00\"`. When I add the quotes to the value above it does deserialize correctly aswell. Is there a way for me to tell json.net to deserialize the timespan without those extra quotes?

Comment: You'll probably want to write a converter, whether that be one for System.Text.Json for serializing, or for JSON.NET when deserializing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I just serialize a TimeSpan the actual JSON text in json.net is the mentioned `"\"02:30:00\""`. In System.Text.Json it's `"02:30:00"`.

Comment: Post the *actual* json text. Only number values can appear without quotes. If your JSON string contains `myProp: 03:30:00` the text is invalid

Comment: `In System.Text.Json it's 02:30:00.` no it's not. JSON is JSON, no matter the library you use to produce it. There's no standard way to serialize durations or time of day (two different things) so you need a converter in *both* cases. In both cases though, the *output* will always be quoted, eg `{ TimeOfDay: "03:30:00"}`

Comment: I think we don't talk about the same. When I serialize *just* timespan. I get the result above. When I serialize a whole dto, I have something like `{ "Property" : "03:30:00"}`. But the point still stands. Json.net wants it to be `{ "Property" : "\"03:30:00\""}`

Comment: The string produced by the default Json.Net serialization of a TimeSpan and  `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteStringValue([TimeSpan].ToString());` is exactly the same. Assuming the same Locale on both sides. If not, change in `writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Comment: @Jimi and PanagiotisKanavos  you both where rights. My reproduction code was flawed. I had a first issue with the timespan that was solved with the converter in my post. After that the immediate message was the same, but the cause was a field in a nested object. Thanks for your help.